# How to execute threads in a DLL in C

Tags: c, windows, dll

I created a DLL that is running 3 worker threads, and the main thread is in a loop waiting for the threads to complete. The threads get created, but no execution to the threads is done.

I have tried setting MessageBox functions inside the function that gets created with CreateThread() but the box does not appear. I have also tried to debug and the return value from CreateThread() is valid so the thread gets created.

```
BOOL WINAPI DllMain() {
   main();
   return 1;
}

int main() {
    HANDLE h1, h2, h3;

    h1 = CreateThread(first)...
    h2 = CreateThread(second)...
    h3 = CreateThread(third)...

   WaitForSingleObject(h3, INFINITE);
   return 1;
}

first() {
    MessageBoxA("print some stuff");
    return;
}
```

I have included some pseudocode of what my layout looks like. I am unable to provide the real code due to the sensitivity of it. However this is what is happening. I use LoadLibrary in another project that loads this .DLL. The DLL gets loaded and DllMain is executed. It then calls my main function which creates 3 threads. Each thread is created. But what is inside of the thread does not execute.

EDIT:

```
// dllmain.cpp : Defines the entry point for the DLL application.
#include <Windows.h>

void mb() {
    MessageBoxW(0, L"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA", L"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAa", 1);
}

void create() {
    HANDLE han;
    DWORD threadId;
    han = CreateThread(NULL, 0, mb, NULL, 0, &threadId);
    han = CreateThread(NULL, 0, mb, NULL, 0, &threadId);
    han = CreateThread(NULL, 0, mb, NULL, 0, &threadId);

}

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain() {
    create();
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: *DllMain* that calls *main*? which is probably called when the *.dll* is loaded in an app (that has another *main*)?

Comment: This was originally a .exe program which is why I have main. I have even tried changing 'main' to 'startmain' and same behavior.

Comment: You can't run a *.dll*. Yo have to create an *.exe* that uses (links or dynamically loads) it. You may have the functions implementations in the *.dll*, but calling them should be made from the *.exe* (**not** in *DllMain*). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dlls/dllmain.

Comment: Yes I know that. I included that in my original post. I use another project that loads the .dll. The other program that loads this dll just does a LoadLibrary which kicks off this DLL soon as it is loaded.

Comment: You're doing it wrongly. Read the link that I included in my previous comment.

Comment: I don't think I am. I have a program (.exe) that does LoadLibrary on my .DLL. When the function loads my DLL, the DLL will load its DllMain. The DllMain then loads a function inside of the DLL called main. Main contains all the code which starts up 3 threads. The threads are getting created because I am getting valid return values. But the code inside the functions that the CreateThread calls is not getting executed.

Comment: Although you say you are "*unable to provide the real code*", that's not what we need here, anway - you are expected to distil that down to a [mcve] instead.  Which you should have no problem creating, without needing any of the sensitive parts.

Comment: When you have a specific problem in code that's too large or too sensitive to post, the best thing to do is to make a small test program that reproduces the problem.  In the process of making that, you may learn which parts of the big program are relevant to the problem and which aren't, and that will often help you find the problem yourself.  If not, it makes it a lot easier for folks on Stack Overflow to help you.  There could be half a dozen different problems here, but there's not enough information for us to help you.

Comment: call `WaitForSingleObject` inside dll entry point is fatal error. your threads even not start.

Comment: I added code that is giving the same issue as my real code. This should print 3 messageboxes but it does not. The threads are created, but they are not executed.

Comment: @Doritos - of course all your threads try enter to loader lock critical section, but you hold it and wait here

Comment: From what I am reading, The threads can be created, but not executed until DLLMAIN returns. Is that what you are referring to?

Comment: yes, exactly, you hold critical section, you must not wait here. and not need wait for thread exit at all. you need add ref to dll before create thread in dll and exit from thread with `FreeLibraryAndExitThread`

Comment: Could you provide an example of that with the code I have provided?

Answer (score 2):

[[MS.Docs]: DllMain entry point](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dlls/dllmain) (**emphasis** is mine) states:

> Calling **functions that require DLLs other than Kernel32.dll may result in problems that are difficult to diagnose**. For example, calling User, Shell, and COM functions can cause access violation errors, because some functions load other system components. Conversely, calling functions such as these during termination can cause access violation errors because the corresponding component may already have been unloaded or uninitialized.

[[MS.Docs]: MessageBox function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-messagebox) resides in ***User32.dll***, so it's ***Undefined Behavior*** (meaning that in different scenarios, it might work, it might work faulty, or it might crash).

Also, as @RbMm noticed, *WaitForSingleObject* **doesn't belong there**. I'm not sure about *CreateThread* either (but I couldn't find any official doc to confirm / infirm it).

Just out of curiosity, could you add a `printf("main called.\n");` in *main*, to see how many times it is called?

Answer (score 2):

because in general case DLL can be unloaded, need add reference to DLL - for it will be not unloaded until thread, which use it code executed. this can be done by call [`GetModuleHandleEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getmodulehandleexw) - *increments the module's reference count unless `GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_UNCHANGED_REFCOUNT` is specified.* when thread exit - we dereference DLL code by call [`FreeLibraryAndExitThread`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-freelibraryandexitthread). wait for all threads exit in most case not need. so code, inside dll can be next

```
ULONG WINAPI DemoThread(void*)
{
    MessageBoxW(0, L"text", L"caption", MB_OK);
    // dereference dlll and exit thread
    FreeLibraryAndExitThread((HMODULE)&__ImageBase, 0);
}

void someFnInDll()
{
    HMODULE hmod;
    // add reference to dll, because thread will be use it
    if (GetModuleHandleExW(GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_FROM_ADDRESS, (PCWSTR)&__ImageBase, &hmod))
    {
        if (HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(0, 0, DemoThread, 0, 0, 0))
        {
            CloseHandle(hThread);
        }
        else
        {
            // dereference dll if thread create fail
            FreeLibrary(hmod);
        }
    }
}
```

---

wait inside dll entry point is wrong, because we hold here process wide critical section. if we wait for thread exit - this wait always deadlock - thread before exit (and start) try enter this critical section, but can not because we wait for him here. so we hold critical section and wait for thread(s), but threads(s) wait when we exit from this critical section. deadlock

Comment: Could you build it into the bottom example on my post? I am trying to incorporate it into what I know. &__ImageBase isn't working. Is this a import?

Comment: @Doritos - `EXTERN_C extern IMAGE_DOS_HEADER __ImageBase;` the [`__ImageBase`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20041025-00/?p=37483) is special symbol for *link.exe*. but however you (if use another linker) can and remember self image base in dll entry point and save it in global var.